# WPF - center TextBlock horizontally on Grid column edges

Tags: wpf, wpf-grid, horizontal-alignment

I have the following Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

I want to place two TextBlocks into this Grid so that the horizontal center of the two TextBlocks to be exactly on the column edges (vertical alignment does not matter):

[image]

The closest I got to it is the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Text="textOfTextBlock1"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"
               Text="textOfTextBlock2"/>
</Grid>
```

which results in

[image]

but if we look closely, the position of the TextBlocks in the two images are not the same, because the actual column widths of the columns having the widths 2*, 1* and 3* are calculated based on the total space that is left **after** the TextBlocks take their widths.

I do not want to specify exact coordinates in the solution, the positions of the TextBlocks should change when the Grid gets resized, of course.

I was also thinking about the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Text="textOfTextBlock1"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"
               Text="textOfTextBlock2"/>
</Grid>
```

but the columns are cutting/clipping the edges of the TextBlocks, so having 0 as the column width for the second and fourth columns the TextBlocks are not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextBlock's Margin can be bound to the ActualWidth of the TextBlock, then setting the Left Margin equal to the ActualWidth / -2 in a converter results in no need to hardcode the Width and Margin of the TextBlocks:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <converters:ActualWidthToNegativeHalfLeftMarginConverter x:Key="ActualWidthToNegativeHalfLeftMarginConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Text="textOfTextBlock1"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock.Margin>
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Converter="{StaticResource ActualWidthToNegativeHalfLeftMarginConverter}" />
        </TextBlock.Margin>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
               Text="textOfTextBlock2"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock.Margin>
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Converter="{StaticResource ActualWidthToNegativeHalfLeftMarginConverter}" />
        </TextBlock.Margin>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

```
public class ActualWidthToNegativeHalfLeftMarginConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Thickness((double)value / -2, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use combinations of multiple `Grid` columns and `ColumnSpan` to achieve effects like this, if you don't mind the extra "dummy" column.

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Text="textOfTextBlock1" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Text="textOfTextBlock2" />
</Grid>
```

[image]